# Different way of using multiple SUMIFS function in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel report which includes a lot of `SUMIFS` functions.

I am updating formulation time to time according to new needs but it's getting more and more difficult every time, and it's getting more difficult to maintain.

For better explanation see sample data.

```
    +--------+--------+
    |    A   |    B   |
+---+--------+--------+
| 1 | Letter | Number |
+---+--------+--------+
| 2 |    A   |   50   |
+---+--------+--------+
| 3 |    B   |   54   |
+---+--------+--------+
| 4 |    W   |   60   |
+---+--------+--------+
| 5 |    A   |   20   |
+---+--------+--------+
| 6 |    N   |   70   |
+---+--------+--------+
| 7 |    B   |   36   |
+---+--------+--------+
```

I am currently writing formulation like this `=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"A")` and add new criteria range and new criterias for additional needs.

So it looks like this,

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"A")+SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"B")+SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"C")+SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"D")+...
```

This is an simple explanation with formulation it gets more complex because I have many criterias.

Is there an easier way or a different formula which gives me the same result with shorter formula?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a full formulation approach to this question. That might seem little awkward but it's logical.

When you are using SUMIFS function, it sums given array and returns one number. There is another way to use same function with returning sum array.

Instead of writing this

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"A")+SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"B")
```

You can use like this

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"A","B"})
```

This formula will return two summed array to you

You can wrap this function with an outer sum to get total result of SUMIFS

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"A","B"}))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would put the criteria into a separate table:

[image]

Like that you can add or remove criteria without touching the formula.

You use this formula to retrieve the sum:
`=SUM(SUMIF(Table1[Letter],Criteria[sumcriteria],Table1[Number]))`

Left table called "Table1", criteria table called "criteria"

Comment: Maybe nice to know:
I thought SUMIFS was slow and tried FILTER, but it turns out that SUMIFS is performing better after all:
tested: `=LET(a,NOW(),b,SUM(SUMIFS(Table1[Number],Table1[Letter],Criteria[sumcriteria])),TEXT(NOW()-a,"hh:mm:ss.000"))`

`=LET(a,NOW(),b,SUM(FILTER(Table1[Number],ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[Letter],Criteria)))),TEXT(NOW()-a,"h:mm:ss.000"))`

it turns out that SUMIFS performs approximately 4x faster. Tested with 70000 rows.

Comment: @P.b nice approach!

Comment: @Ike ma'm i must say your solution is dynamic and its not hardcoded, which should work more dynamically, even OP can make changes to criteria as all P.b Sirs is always good as usual!